# Android studio set int to textView from one activity to other

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to set data in TextView from one activity to another activity

This is my main activity, I want when the user login successfully to show his ID in TextView. This is the variable which i want to send "IdAccount". And this is the other activity "login_successfully". I want to set it in this textView "textViewId"

```
package com.example.cinemaweb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private String ip = "192.168.0.106";
    private String port = "1433";
    private String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private String db = "AdminToolWeb";
    private String un = "mssqllogin";
    private String password = "mssqllogin$";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                EditText usernameUser = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText);
                EditText passwordUser = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText2);

                String strUsernameUser=usernameUser.getText().toString();
                String strPasswordUser=passwordUser.getText().toString();


                Connection conn = null;
                String ConnURL = null;
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                try {
                    Class.forName(classs);
                    ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip +":"+port+";"
                            + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                            + password + ";";
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("select * from AndroidLogin where Username = '" + strUsernameUser + "' and Password = '" + strPasswordUser + "'");
                    int IdAccount = 0;
                    if (resultat.next()) {
                        IdAccount = resultat.getInt("ID_Accounts");


                        setContentView(R.layout.login_successfully);
                    } else {
                        openDialog();
                    }
                    resultat.close();
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

This is my login_successfully.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="663dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login successfully" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="564dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login successfully" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you how to send this ID?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to write another activity class and instead of setContentView you can

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("IdAccount", IdAccount);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in onCreate of `YourNewActivity`  you can use

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("IdAccount",0);
```

after that you can use `findViewById(yourTextViewId)` and set the text

Comment: Give me this error error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<ActivityMenu>) in the first row

Comment: Try:
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity.class);